# How can I convert record set from database to array?

Tags: php

How can I convert record set from database to array?
It has 1 table named: `tblproduct`, with the following schema:

```
 product_id | product_name | product_desc | product_price | product_img
```

When I select data from the database I would like an array in the following format:

```
$product_array = array(
  "105" => array('product_id' => '105', 'product_name' => 'Blackberry 8900',
                 'product_desc' => '', 'product_price' => '1150.00',
                 'product_img' => 'products/product5.jpg'),
  "106" => array('product_id' => '106', 'product_name' => 'Headphone with mic',
                 'product_desc' => '', 'product_price'=>'148.85', 
                 'product_img' => 'products/product8.jpg')
);
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQL (You didn't specify your DBMS) and have a line like:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `tblproduct`');
```

You can use:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    $product_array[$row['product_id']] = $row;
```

Comment: @user872147 Ll I'm no expert yet ;) You're welcome. If this answer solved your problem you can accept it by  clicking the checkmark under the vote count to the left of my answer :)

Comment: he is not expert yet he is just a PRO xD